# Laravel 8 route login not found with api 401 errors

Tags: php, laravel

Am using laravel 8 and also using the auth:api middleware in my api routes. In my request url am setting the correct bearer token with `Bearer token` with the token been generated by passport. This works well but whenever a request has an expired token it throws a Route [login] not defined error

I have the following in my api routes

```
Route::middleware("auth:api")->group(function (){
   Route::resource("users",UserController::class);
});
```

I have also added the following to my `app\Exceptions\Handler.php`

```
class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
 {
        public function report(Throwable $exception)
        {

         if ($exception instanceof \League\OAuth2\Server\Exception\OAuthServerException && $exception->getCode() == 9) {
            return response('unauthorized', 401);
         }

         parent::report($exception);
       }
 }
```

But the above still doesnt work. What do i need to add to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because Laravel is probably throwing `AuthenticationException` exception. That logic is defined in the the default `Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php` in the method `unauthenticated()`:

```
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    if ($request->expectsJson()) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
    }

    return redirect()->guest(route('login'));
}
```

As you can see, in this default example, if your API excepts a JSON response, you would get JSON response with `401 HTTP` code. If that's not the case, you would be redirected to the login (hence the error, because you don't have the login route defined)

So, in order to solve this, you can do two things.

The first one is to override this method and actually write your own condition and responses. You can do that by just defining `unauthenticated()` method in your custom `Handler.php`. You could do something like this:

```
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    //This will return just a plain 401 page
    return response('Unauthenticated.', 401);
}
```

But, since this is probably an API, it would be better to use the second solution, which would be to just include `Accept: application/json` in your request header. This tells your API that you are sending a `JSON` request. In this case, you don't need to override the `unauthenticated()`, because this exception will be caught in the following condition, from the default Laravel handler:

```
if ($request->expectsJson()) {
   return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
}
```

When this block of code is triggered, you will get a JSON response with 401 HTTP code, which is the expected one for the API's. If you need any more help, let me know.